# What is the `[` program that resides in my system's /bin?

Tags: fedora, gnu, coreutils

I was recently browsing my Fedora's `/bin` folder and noticed a binary named `[`. 
I did try to search the internet for more information on that, but I couldn't find anything useful. Running it through `strace` doesn't seem to produce anything useful for closer inspection too.

What is that? Should I be alarmed? Could it be the result of a system compromise? Should I run it? Does it belong to any package?

Comment: `[ -f /bin/[ ] && printf "%s\n" "Don't panic"`

Comment: @jasonwryan Yeah, it took me a while to figure it out. I couldn't find much information for it on the net, and Google didn't help much. Posted it here in hopes that it might help the next one who's in my shoes.

Comment: Run `man [` to see what the `[` command is!

Comment: @Gilles To be honest, I did and it mentioned something about `bash`, and figured that might be something else. It's not the first thing that comes to your mind when you see a binary with a name you've never seen before in your file system - or to put it another way, you have to find something more concrete to clear the doubts in your head.

Comment: Related: [Confusing use of && and || operators](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/confusing-use-of-and-operators/24685#24685)

Comment: Do a`rpm -qif /bin/[` to find out where it comes from...

Comment: @Gilles `$ man [` -- `No manual entry for [`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `[` binary residing under the `/bin` tree in many GNU/Linux distributions is not something to be alarmed off. At least in my Fedora 19 it is a part of the coreutils package, as demonstrated below:

```
$ rpm -qf /bin/[
coreutils-8.21-13.fc19.x86_64
```

and is a synonym for `test` to allow for expressions like `[ expression ]` to be written in shell scripts or even interactive usage.

Comment: Note that shells like `bash` have a builtin `test` and `[` and do not invoke the external binary.

Comment: @jordanm, today most shells have them (and many other simple, common operations) as builtins. But that wasn't allways so (or is so in all shells). It might even be mandated by POSIX.

Comment: @vonbrand http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html You are right. A test command `[` is required by this specification.

Comment: @vonbrand, only Bourne-like shells generally have a builtin `[` command. Non-Bourne-like ones like `(t)csh`, `rc`, `es` generally don't (`fish` is an exception there).

Answer (score 5):

The `[` command is the same as the `test` command.

It allows you to write rather terse conditional statements in shell scripts.  From the SunOS manual page:

```
   if [ "$1" = "pear" ] || [ "$1" = "grape" ] || [ "$1" = "apple" ]
   then
       command
   fi
```

If you remove it, scripts will break!

Comment: Scripts written for shells that don't have `[` as a built-in command will break. Most shells do. Still, I certainly wouldn't recommend removing `/bin/[`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, all shells have `[` builtin, it's scripts that have non-shell applications execute `[` that will break. Like `find ... -exec [ -f {} ] \;` or `env LC_ALL=C [ -f bar ]`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: *All* shells? (csh and tcsh don't, but perhaps that's beside the point.) I don't think I've seen an sh-derived shell that doesn't have `[` as a builtin, but don't think `[` was a builtin in the original Bourne shell. In any case, removing `/bin/[` would certainly be a bad idea.

Comment: Minor quibble: `test` and `[` are *almost* the same. `[` requires a closing `]`; `test` does not allow it (or rather doesn't treat an argument of `]` specially).

Answer (score 2):

The [ is always given as an equivalent to test, but I had'nt seen the ] mentioned explicitly, although it is always there. I have just now found this in http://ss64.com/bash/test.html :

```
When the [ form is used, the last argument to the command must be a ]
```

which is reassuring -- at last I have completion as they say.