# How exactly does "/bin/[" work?

Tags: shell, test

I am always surprised that in the folder `/bin` there is a `[` program.

Is this what is called when we are doing something like: `if [ something ]`?

By calling the `[` program explicitly in a shell it asks for a corresponding `]`, and when I provide the closing bracket it seems to do nothing no matter what I insert between the brackets.

Needless to say, the usual way about getting help about a program does not work, i.e. neither `man [` nor `[ --help` works.

Comment: try `man expr`.

Comment: @IporSircer  `[` refers to `test` command though, not `expr` , so it should be `man test`

Comment: oops. sorry! i was tired.

Comment: `man '['` works fine for me - either you forgot to quote `[` or you have a different definition of "works".

Comment: @TobySpeight  See my and Stephane's answers. `[` has  OS-specific implementations , which may or may not have a man page

Comment: A few warnings: `[` evaluates its arguments, so you need to have spaces between all of them.  `[ a=b ]` is not a comparison: it will always be true (it is a single string: "a=b", which is *always evaluated to true*) And you should limit the number of arguments to 4 (even though recent implementations will allow more... limiting to 4 makes it more portable. For example : `[ "a" = "b" ]` already has 4 arguments : "a" "=" "b" and the non-necessary end of test arg : "]" ). If you need more: chain tests with for example: `if [ "$Var_a" = "foo" ] && [ "$Var_b" = "bar" ] ; then : do something ; fi`

Comment: And as your arguments are passed to `[` (the builtin version if your shell has one, or the one in `/bin/[` ) : ensure your shell really passes what you want it to pass. For that, you may need to escape some arguments. For example to negate, use `'!'` or `\!` if you use bash, otherwise bash will try to replace `!` by the last command in history... ex: `if [ \! -f "$1" ]; then echo "we need an existing regular file as first argument" ; fi` is usually more portable than `if [ ! -f "$1" ]` which may fail in bash as it will try to replace `!` .

Comment: @OlivierDulac a `!` by itself (unescaped and unquoted) won't be replaced, and even better would be `if ! [ ...`. All of the bash expansions that use `!` include at least on other character

Comment: @muru: well, I stand corrected! Which is weird because I've seen "!" replacement occur so many times that I now systematically escape it (hence I didn't notice it would work there...). I'm quite sure it happened (for exemple inside double quotes), even with no trailing character, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/what-is-the-program-that-resides-in-my-systems-bin

Comment: You should also note that there is also a `[`-builtin in `bash` (and possibly other shells as well), and that this may be used instead of `/bin/[`.  Also there is the `test`-command, which on many systems is a symbolic link to `/bin/[` (or vice versa) - but on others is a separate command.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `[` command's job is to evaluate test expressions. It returns with a 0 exit status (that means *true*) when the expression resolves to true and something else (which means *false*) otherwise.

It's not that it does nothing, it's just that its outcome is to be found in its exit status. In a shell, you can find out about the exit status of the last command in `$?` for Bourne-like shells or `$status` in most other shells (fish/rc/es/csh/tcsh...).

```
$ [ a = a ]
$ echo "$?"
0
$ [ a = b ]
$ echo "$?"
1
```

In other languages like `perl`, the exit status is returned for instance in the return value of `system()`:

```
$ perl -le 'print system("[", "a", "=", "a", "]")'
0
```

Note that all modern Bourne-like shells (and `fish`) have a built-in `[` command. The one in `/bin` would typically only be executed when you use another shell or when you do things like `env [ foo = bar ]` or `find . -exec [ -f {} ] \; -print` or that `perl` command above...

The `[` command is also known by the `test` name. When called as `test`, it doesn't require a closing `]` argument.

While your system may not have a man page for `[`, it probably has one for `test`. But again, note that it would document the `/bin/[` or `/bin/test` implementation.  To know about the `[` builtin in your shell, you should read the documentation for your shell instead.

For more information about the history of that utility and the difference with the `[[...]]` ksh test expression, you may want to have a look at this [other Q&A here](/a/56674).

Comment: Good, as usual. You may want to add in the comments I added underneath @Bregalad question? or maybe some extra ones? That way the answer will be even more complete on "how exactly does it work" (I note that you already gave a more acurate info about "]" than I did ^^)

Comment: “all Bourne-like shells (and fish) have a built-in [ command” That's true in practice in the 21st century, but I'm pretty sure I've used a shell without `[`. I don't remember if it was a Bourne variant or an antique version of ash.

Comment: @Gilles The Bourne shell implemented both `[` and `test` as builtins with Unix System III. Before that, there was no `[` and `test` was only an external binary command.

Comment: @Gilles, the original ash had test builtin (merged with expr), but _optionally_. According to http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/, BSDs didn't have test builtin until around 2000. I've added "modern".

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do `find . -exec [ f {} ] \; -print`? The command `find . -type f -print` would do the same thing _so_ much more efficiently...

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname, no, for the equivalent of `-exec [ -f {} ] \;` (check that the file is regular after symlink resolution), you'd need the GNU-specific `-xtype f`. Other `find` implementation have no equivalent (using `-L`/`-follow` have other undesirable side-effects).

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname. (continued), You can optimise by doing `\( -type f -o -type l -exec [ -f {} ] \; \)` or invoke `sh` with `-exec {} +` to run the `[` builtin in a loop, but that's beyond the point of this Q&A. Note that there's no point using `env [ ... ]`, those are just to give example of when `/bin/[` may be executed.

Answer (score 43):

> I am always surprised that in the folder `/bin` there is a `[` program.

You are right to be surprised. That's one of the rare POSIX commands, with the null utility (`:`), that doesn't respect the commands file allowed characters convention (portable filename character set).

> Is is what is called when we are doing something like: `if [ something ]`?

Precisely but it can be used without the `if` too.

> By calling the `[` program explicitly in a shell it asks for a corresponding `]`, and when I provide the closing bracket it seems to do nothing no matter what I insert between the brackets.

It does nothing visible but it actually does the very same thing than when used with `if`, i.e. it sets the exit status to 0 (true) or anything else (false) depending on what you put inside the brackets. It is (for a reason) the same behavior as the `test` command; the only difference is that it looks for the ending `]`. See [`man test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) for details.

> Needless to say, the usual way about getting help about a program does not work, i.e. neither `man [` nor `[ --help` works.

That depends on your Operating System. `man [` definitely works for me on a couple of mainstream Gnu/Linux distributions but it doesn't on Solaris.

`[ --help` might work or not depending on the implementation as it is breaking the syntax anyway, missing the ending `]`. Moreover, the [POSIX standard for the `test` / `[` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) explicitly rules out all options, including the `--` option termination so both `[ --help ]` and `test --help` need to return `true` and be silent by design. Note that what you put inside the brackets or after `[` and that look like options (e.g. `-f file`, `-n string`, and the likes) are not *options* but *operands*.

All modern Bourne style shell interpreters (like `bash`, `ksh`, `dash` and `zsh` to name a few) implement the `test`/`[` utility internally as a builtin so when you use them, the right manual page to refer to might be the one of the shell, not the `test` one.

Before Unix System III (1981), the Bourne shell didn't implemented the `test` utility as a builtin so only the external binary command implementation was available. There wasn't either a `[` command (internal or builtin) until Unix System III so for example under Unix Version 7 you had to type:

```
if test something ; then
…
```

instead of:

```
if [ something ] ; then
…
```

Comment: "man [ definitely works for me on mainstream Gnu/Linux distributions" Hmm.. Centos (admittedly 6.8 still) clearly isn't mainstream enough :)  `man test` works but not `man [`  On the other hand my cygwin environment does known about `man [`!

Comment: @Adam Yes, you are right, that's more recent than I thought although I didn't wrote **all** mainstream Linux distros, just that it worked for me (i.e. on the ones I tested). That is OL 7.2 (RHEL 7.2) clone and Mint 17.1 (Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: `man [` doesn't seem to work on Manjaro (Arch Linux based). The manual for `test` lists `[ --help` as a valid invocation that should show help, but interestingly it doesn't, and instead complains about a missing `]`, same as with `--version`. Adding the `]` doesn't do anything, so it seems impossible to get help other than from `man test`.

Comment: @Darkhogg You can try `/usr/bin/[ --help` or `/bin/[ --help`.

Comment: @jlliagre You are completely right, I was using the builtins. `env [ --help` as well as `/usr/bin/[ --help` work completely fine (although I need to quote `/usr/bin/[` or zsh complains).

Answer (score 10):

`[` is actually more commonly known as `test` command. Typical use of this command is simply to evaluate expressions and return their condition - true or false.  It is often used in `if-then-else-fi` statements, although it can be used outside of `if` statements to conditionally run other commands via shell's `&&` or `||` operators, like so.

```
$ [ -e /etc/passwd  ] && echo "File exists"
File exists

$ test -e /etc/passwd && echo "File exists"
File exists
```

More specifically, evaluation is communicated to other commands via exit status. Some programs may choose to output exit status to signify different types of events - program completing successfully, an error of particular type occurring during execution, or syntax errors. In the case of the `test` command, there are `0` signifies true, and `1` signifies false. As Stephan pointed out, syntax errors produce exit status of `2`.

Its location depends on your system, and it also explains why you didn't see man page when you did `man [`. For instance, on FreeBSD it is under `/bin`. On Linux (or in my particular case, Ubuntu 16.04) it is in `/usr/bin/`.   If you do `man [` or `man test` on a Linux system, you will see same documentation open. It's also important to note that your shell  may have its own implementation of `test`.

It should also be noted that this command has [issues](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest), which Korn shell's implementation (commonly known as ["conditional expression"](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) reference with double square brackets, `[[ "$USER" = "root" ]]` ) seeks to resolve. This feature also used by other shells such as `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/` for Amazon Linux as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you. Answer edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

> Neither `man [` nor `[ --help` works

On some distros (e.g. Ubuntu), `man [` follows a symlink to `test(1)`.  On others (e.g. Arch), this is not the case.  (But the `test` man page does document usage of `[` as well)

---

`type -a [` shows you that there's both a shell builtin and an executable.

```
$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /usr/bin/[
```

bash-builtin `[ --help` just prints an error message.  (But since it's a builtin, you can use `help [`, or look at the bash man page / docs).

`/usr/bin/[ --help` prints full help output (for the GNU Coreutils version), which starts out with:

```
$ /usr/bin/[ --help
Usage: test EXPRESSION
  or:  test
  or:  [ EXPRESSION ]
  or:  [ ]
  or:  [ OPTION
Exit with the status determined by EXPRESSION.

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

and then describes the allowed syntax for EXPRESSION.

This is another way you could have found out that `[` and `test` are equivalent.

---

BTW, if you are programming for bash (or writing one-liners interactively), I'd recommend `[[` instead of `[`.  It's better in several ways, see links in Serg's answer.

Answer (score 2):

`[` command returns exit-status zero if expression, contained in its arguments, is considered true and non-zero exit-status if expression, contained in its arguments, is considered false. It also fails with error message if its last argument isn't `]` (this is done purely for aesthetic reasons).

E.g.:

```
[ hello ]
echo "Exit-status of [ hello ] is:" $?
[ abc = abc ]
echo "Exit-status of [ abc = abc ] is:" $?
[ ]
echo "Exit-status of [ ] is:" $?
[ abc = def ]
echo "Exit-status of [ abc = def ] is:" $?
```

… will output:

```
Exit-status of [ hello ] is: 0      — because non-empty string is considered true
Exit-status of [ abc = abc ] is: 0  — because 'abc' really is same as 'abc'
Exit-status of [ ] is: 1            — because empty string is considered false
Exit-status of [ abc = def ] is: 1  — because 'abc' really differs from 'def'
```

However, [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) and many other shells really usually don't invoke `/bin/[` (or `/usr/bin/[`) in these cases, but call built-in command with exactly the same behavior instead (purely for performance reasons). To invoke `/bin/[` (not shell built-in surrogate) you need either to explicitly specify its path (e.g. `/bin/[ hello ]`<sub>; you don't need to prefix `]` with dirname though ☺</sub>), or to configure shell not to use a built-in surrogate (for example, `enable -n [` in bash).

P. S.: As it was said in other answers, `[` is related to `test`. But `test`, unlike `[`, doesn't require `]` as its last argument <sub>(and doesn't expect it at all; adding extra `]` to `test` arguments can cause it to fail with error message or to return wrong result)</sub>. <sub>The `/bin/test` and `/bin/[` can resolve to the same file (e.g. one is [symlinked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link); in this case the behavior diversion is probably implemented by [analyzing the currently-called command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2805165/1421194) within the `test`/`[` code itself) or to different files. For `test`, shell also usually invokes built-in surrogate, unless path is explicitly specified (`/bin/test`) or it's configured not to do so (`enable -n test`).</sub>

P. P. S.: Unlike `test` and `[`, modern `if` is never a real file. It's part of shell (e.g. bash) syntax: `if commandA; then commandB; fi` (newlines can be used instead of semicolons) causes `commandB` to be executed if-and-only-if `commandA` exited with zero status. This perfectly fits to behavior of `test` or `[`, allowing to combine them like `if [ "$a" = foo ]; then …; fi` <sub>(or `if test "$a" = foo; then …; fi` — just less readable)</sub>. However, modern scripts often use `[[` instead of `test` or `[`, which (as the `if`) is never a real file, but always a part of shell syntax.

P. P. P. S.: As for `man` — never expect `man` to have an article on every command in your file-system. Info on some (even "real", file-based) commands may be missing, info on some shell built-ins maybe present not only within an article dedicated to specific shell (that's the place where you most certainly will find info on `test`, `[`, `if`, `[[`). Still, many distributions have explicit `man`-articles for `test` and `[`. (About `--help`, it's not recognized with `test` for obvious reason: it needs to handle quietly cases like `a=--help; test "$a"`; on some distributions `[ --help` (without closing `]`) still shows help, on some it doesn't.)

Comment: Note that `if` was a command up to Unix V6. Unix V7 (1979) came with the Bourne shell (with its `if-then-else-fi` construct) and the new `test` command.