# Why doesn't the conditional work when I use it directly without a variable?

Tags: bash, variable, command-substitution, test

This gives me an error that says too many arguments:

```
if [ $( file -b $i ) == "directory" ]
```

But when I tried this

```
name=$( file -b $i )
if [ name == "directory" ]
```

It seems to work just fine.

Can someone explain this or point out in the docs an explanation?

Comment: Right from the start your square brackets are not balanced in the first case.  (one too many `]`)

Comment: @JuliePelletier Oops sorry that was a typo from the stackoverflow side. I will edit my question. I confirmed there is not an extra ] in my code and it still gives "too many arguments" on that line

Comment: On top of the two good answers you got, I'd also like to add that the only case that I was able to reproduce your error is when the file referred by `$i` doesn't exist, which denotes another thing you should check.

Comment: @JuliePelletier $i is in a `for i in ...` loop and echoes alright in scope. You're right that $i has been the problem. Thanks for helping yall

Comment: look for a tool called **shellcheck** to test your own scripts, it's s great learning tool for basic mistakes like this

Comment: @muru you just changed the question (to fix the code), but now it saw this perfectly good code gives an error (that it does not).

Comment: @richard OP said in a comment that was a typo and that the extra ] is not in the actual code

Comment: Background reading: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), [What is the difference between `[[ $a == z* ]]` and `[ $a == z* ]`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56655/what-is-the-difference-between-a-z-and-a-z)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- `]` indicates the end of arguments for `[` (`test`), and it must be the last argument; you have couple of `]`s, which is wrong; presumably you meant to use:

  ```
  if [ $( file -b $i ) == "directory" ]
  ```
- If you had used the above, you would get `bash: [: too many arguments`, because word splitting would be done upon on the output of the variable expansion (`$i`), and then command substitution, `$()` (`file` command) and `[` will see multiple words before `=`, leading to the error message. You need to quote the variable expansion, and  command substitution:

  ```
  [ "$(file -b "$1")" == "directory" ]
  ```

As a side note, you should use the `bash` keyword `[[`, instead of `[` as the former will handle word splitting (and pathname expansion) for you.

Comment: Thanks, the [[ tip works well. Also "$()" makes sense too.

Comment: @ScriptKitty Note the `"$i"` as well.

Comment: @ScriptKitty  did `$i` have spaces in filename ?

Comment: @Serg Why not follow the usual and safer route rather than confirming? :)

Comment: @Serg not at test time, it still gave me an error I think.

Comment: @heemayl  by "safe and usual" route , I assume you mean quoting the variables - with which I absolutely agree , and that should be done in first place. I'm just curious what's user's specific case is :)

Answer (score 4):

```
if [ $( file -b $i ) == "directory" ]
```

Two issues here:

- Use single `=` for string comparison. See `man test` for proper syntax( note, that `[` in many cases has shell-specific implementation, so see your shell's `man page` if you don't have documentation for `test`). If you absolutely need `==` , use `[[` instead, which is feature of many bourne-like shells, including bash,ksh,zsh.   NOTE: while `==` exists in bash [since version 2.0](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges), " = should be used with the test command for POSIX conformance." ( [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)).
- Quote all your variables as `"$()"` . Specifically of interest is `$i`. Filenames with space will break `$i` into multiple words due to shell's word expansion.

Example:

```
bash-4.3$ mkdir with\ space
bash-4.3$ i="./with space"
bash-4.3$ set -x
bash-4.3$ [ $( file -b $i ) == "directory" ] && echo "YES"
++ file -b ./with space
+ '[' cannot open '`./with'\''' '(No' such file or 'directory)' cannot open '`space'\''' '(No' such file or 'directory)' == directory ']'
bash: [: too many arguments
```

---

```
name=$( file -b $i )
if [ name == "directory" ]
```

Issues here:

- `name` is not expanded to variable, it's just a string "name" here. You need `"$name"` and again, single `=`

Also, it cannot have possibly have worked , since exit status of `test` is returned as false ( exit status 1)

```
$ name=$(file -b /etc)
$ set -x
$ [ name == "directory" ]
+ '[' name '==' directory ']'
$ echo $?
+ echo 1
1
```

The above tested on `bash` and `mksh` shells.

Comment: Since `[` / `test` is a bash built-in, it's better to use `help test`, not `man test`.

Comment: @Patrick  true, although it depends on the OS person uses. It might not have any documentation at all. See this post from a few days ago : http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336521/85039

Comment: Actually it doesn't depend on the OS. The builtin `[` and `test` commands will always take precedence over the OS ones.

Comment: @Patrick What I mean is  presence of documentation for standard `test` command depends on the OS.

Comment: @Patrick by the way, this slightly overdue of a comment ( I'm not the fastest guy on U&L ) , but bash isn't the only shell that uses  `test`, so I'm not sure if it's OK to make assumptions for what's OP is using.

Comment: @Serg lol I'm now on mac, but want to use the script on ubuntu. TIL what test is

Comment: @ScriptKitty Glad I could assist in learning :D  If you just write the script in `bash` it should work. Are you going to be using any special path names at all ? I know Macs don't have `/proc` directory. There's `/Volumes` also, which exists on Mac but not on Linux. Not sure about other pitfalls,though, but in general if you're not using anything mac-specific, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of issues! Let’s take this part which is "working":

```
 name=$( file -b $i )
 if [ name == "directory" ]
```

This assigns the output of the file command to the variable called `name`, but doesn't use it; instead, it runs the `[` command with 3 parameters: `name`, `==`, and `directory`. Accepting `==` is a bash extension.

If this was corrected to use `$name` rather than `name` you would again get a `too many arguments` problem for many cases. This is because `file` returns multiple word results like `ASCII text`. So after the command has run you get

```
if [ ASCII text == directory ]
```

and now it is obvious that the command is missing some grouping.

```
if [ "$(file -b -- "$i")" = "directory" ]
```

is probably what you want: `=` rather than `==` for portability, and quoting the result of command substitution **which you almost always want to do**.

Comment: I actually like this answer too because it spelled out the unquoted part

Comment: Of course, as the other answers have said, it is also necessary to put the `$i` in quotes: ``"$(file -b "$i")"``. This may appear to be an improper nesting of quotes; see [Bash quotes unescaped on command substitution](//superuser.com/q/909764/150988).