# What does -f mean in an if statement in a bash script?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Trying to understand this piece of code:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

I'm not sure what the -f means exactly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relevant man page to check for this is that of the shell itself, `bash`, because `-f` is functionality that the shell provides, it's a bash built-in.

On my system (CentOS 7), the fine man page covers it.  The `grep` may not give the same results on other distributions.  Nevertheless, if you run `man bash` and then search for '-f' it should give the results you require.

```
$ man bash | grep -A1 '\-f file$'
       -f file
              True if file exists and is a regular file.
$
```

Comment: -1 This answer is very misleading, following on from the question’s misleading title. `-f` has nothing to do with `if`; it is an option for the `[` command, which just happens to be called using an `if` statement here. Also, it just so happens that `[` (along with `if`) is built in to `bash`.

Comment: Yeah, agree that this is a terrible answer. If you run `man [` in a linux terminal, you'll see that `-f` is an option of the `[` operator. From there it's apparent what `-f` does.

Answer (score 31):

In short, the piece of code will source `/etc/bashrc` file if it exists, and the existence is verified by `[` command to which `-f` is an operator/parameter.

`if...then...else...fi` statement in shell scripting evaluates exit status of commands - 0 on success. So it's proper to do something like this:

```
if ping -c 4 google.com; then
    echo "We have a connection!"
fi
```

The command, in your case, is `[` which is also known as `test` command. So it'd be perfectly valid to do

```
if test -f /etc/bashrc; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

The -f flag verifies two things: the provided path exists and is a regular file. If `/etc/bashrc` is in fact a directory or missing, test should return non-zero exit status to signal failure

This command originally was a separate command, that is not part of shell's built-in commands. Nowadays, most Bourne-like shells have it as built-in, and that's what shell will use.

On a side note, the `/etc/bashrc` seems like  unnecessary extra file that your admin or original author of the code snippet is using. There exists `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which is intended as system-wide rc-file for bash, so one would expect that to be used.

See also:

- [How to conditionally do something if a command succeeded or failed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22726/85039)
- [How exactly does “/bin/[” work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336521/85039)
- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/85039)