# bash_aliases and "if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then . ~/.bash_aliases fi" meaning

Tags: bash, kali-linux, alias

There's a short section in my `.bashrc` file that I don't understand and I'd like to ask what it means and some syntax explanation.

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

I understand of course that # makes every line a comment.

Can you please explain to me the `if ... then` statement.
What `-f` means?

Why there are `[]` in the first line of the code?

Why there's `;` after the `[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]`?

Why the second line of the code starts with a `.` and what it actually means, this whole second line.
I know that `.bash_aliases` is a file containing bash_aliases in Linux, but this second line I don't understand.

Comment: Related: [What does -f mean in an if statement in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453502/what-does-f-mean-in-an-if-statement-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -f mean in an if statement in a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453502/what-does-f-mean-in-an-if-statement-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: It almost feels like we have duplicate comments suggesting that this question is a duplicate? Can that be right? On a more serious note, that question’s answer does not explain the `.`, so it is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: @Quasímodo I assume that before doing any of that, we should head to the proposed duplicate and cast some downvotes and close votes there. It currently has a score of 9 and two answers. One answer is dodgy, but even that answer has a score of 10. There seem to be a lot of inconsistencies here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. *Can you please explain to me the `if ... then` statement.*

   In plain English:
   If there is a file named `.bash_aliases` in your home directory, source it.
2. *What `-f` means?*:

   Test if a file exists and is a regular file (not a directory etc.), or a symbolic link to a regular file.
3. *Why there are `[]` in the first line of the code?*

   That's the shell command for performing a test. An alternative way is `if test -f .bash_aliases; then`
4. *Why there's `;` after the `[ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]`?*

   The semicolon is a command separator in bash. You need it here to end the `test` command and allow the `then` block to start on the same line.

   Alternatively, you can avoid using the `;` as a separator and explicitly split the commands using a line break.

   ```
   if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]
   then
   ```
5. *Why the second line of the code starts with a `.` and what it actually means*

   That's the name of a command to execute.  The `.` (dot) command is a shell builtin command that sources a file. With the reasonable assumption that `bash` will execute the file `.bashrc`, the more readable but non-POSIX command `source` may be used instead of `.`

   ```
   source ~/.bash_aliases
   ```

Be aware that some shells, for example `dash` and some variants of `ksh`, do not support `source` though.

You might want to read [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: `[` is a program. You will find it in `/bin/[`. Some shells may optimise by handling it internally instead of calling the actual executable.

Comment: @OrangeDog There is no guarantee that the shell’s built-in `[` will behave the same way as the external command in `/bin/[`. Indeed, my Debian 10 system’s man page for `[` says: “Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports.”

Comment: @BrianDrake they are guaranteed to behave in exactly the same way. Especially if the docs for one refer you to the other.

Comment: @OrangeDog Although an identical behavior is expected in most cases, there is not guarantee that both always behave the same way. For example errors message might vary.

Comment: @OrangeDog The `[` man page I cited gives a complete description of the external `[` command, before stating that the shell may have its own version and referring the user to the shell’s documentation. The `bash` man page also has a complete description of `bash`’s implementation. A cursory look suggests that there are at least two differences: only `bash`’s implementation supports `-a` as a synonym for `-e`, and only the external command supports `-l` for the length of a string.