# Is "/bin/[.exe" a legitimate file? [Cygwin, Windows 10]

Tags: shell, cygwin

I can not find anything about this, is it a known file?
I am using a CYGWIN based terminal on windows 10

Here are their locations and the commands I used.

```
$ find -name [*
./bin/[.exe
./usr/bin/[.exe
```

```
$ ls -l -a -r /* | grep [-.*\>]
...all other files that match this...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 X 197121   67134 Nov  6 14:22 [.exe
drwxr-xr-x 1 X 197121       0 Apr  2 18:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 X 197121       0 Jan 26 03:20 .
```

I would like more information on this file and whether or not I can remove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should *not* remove that file. In general, don't remove random files that you have not created yourself.

It's the executable file for the `[` utility.  This utility is exactly the same as the `test` utility but requires that the last operand is `]`.

See `man [` and `man test`.

Example of use:

```
[ -n "hello" ] && echo '"hello" is a non-empty string'
```

You would also be able to use

```
/bin/[.exe -n "hello" ] && echo 'That works too'
```

(though you don't need to specify the `.exe` suffix on the command line)

Note that `/bin/[.exe` is the executable file for the *external* `[` utility. This utility is very often also available as a built-in utility in your shell.  If your shell is `bash`, then `man bash` (and `help [`) would document it.

The external `[` in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` is used by shells that don't have this utility as a built-in, or when executing a test from something that is not a shell (e.g. with `-exec` through `find`).

Related:

- [How exactly does "/bin/[" work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336521/how-exactly-does-bin-work)

Comment: This is ironically enough, hilarious. I did not know that was a legitimate executable. I thought it as a potential security risk through a regex related attack. Thank you very much for this information, it was thoroughly explained well,... formerly not, (now should be for others), provided through google/forum indexing.

Comment: Searching for punctuation is problematic...