# One prompt pkexec - two command

Tags: bash, command-line, virtual-machine, polkit, virsh

Someone could answer me how make one prompt via `pkexec` when I've to use two command with authentication?
My easy sample script:

```
pkexec virsh net-start default;
pkexec "/home/user/program";
```

I'm new in linux environmen,
Thanks :)

Comment: do you really need to use `pkexec`, or could you use instead `sudo` which I know has a window on authentication or can be configured to allow `NOPASSWD` for certain commands

Comment: @thrig i tried use sudo without any effect. I changed I changed chown file on root and doesn't. Could you show some example used twice sudo in one script?

Comment: I added to sudo nano /etc/sudoers:
`%sudo   ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /home/Ham/.config/folder/start.sh`
Next I ran my .desktop app (it has Exec=/home/Ham/.config/folder/start.sh) and it didn'y working. When I run from my terminal that command `/home/Ham/.config/folder/start.sh` then it work. I don't understand what I do wrong..

Comment: what exactly is in `start.sh` and what exactly needs to be run as `root`?

Comment: in start.sh is:
1st command: virsh which allow me set network to guest (for root).
2nd command: run app like gnome-boxes (for root the same as above)
Why I need run/open both command via root? I 've to run this command as root bc then I can mount usb device. Simple user can't do that. For example:
"sudo virsh net-star =/= virsh net start" <- these are different network space

Comment: running a `root` program connecting to your user X11 might be a little bit tricky, though there's probably other questions about that on this site

Comment: that's why I thought the best way is to use polkit (gui with root privileges)

Comment: Untested; can you run both commands under one shell? `pkexec sh -c “virsh... ; /home/user/program”`

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes I can do it. Problem's opening twice windows where I must enter root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old answer.:
*May you take pkexec out of the script? Try create next script where you paste your code (without pkexec) and execute him via pkexec from your script.
your script: `#!/bin/bash pkexec ./new_script`
new script:  `#!/bin/bash your command:`*

**Edit.: New Answer**

After your conversation with @Thrig, I guess what you are going to do.
You want to run both programs on root permissions without double authentication (only once). These two programs are: "virsh" and "gnome-boxes". My previous (above) solution is ok, but not in this case. You wrote to @Thrig that you are considering using "sudo". Why not use "pkexec" and "sudo" together. With the proper completion of "/ etc / sudoers" you will not need to authenticate when you use the "sudo" command in the script. I let myself improve your idea. I hope you like it. I will describe everything step by step.

**1.** Create three scripts:

a) main.sh - set up the connection, destroy the connection, run gnome-boxes. everything as root

b) net.sh - execute the order

c) die.sh - execute the order

a)

```
#!/Bin/bash
sudo /home/ham/..your..path../net.sh && pkexec /usr/bin/gnome-boxes;
sudo /home/ham/..your..path../die.sh;
exit
```

why that? [description of operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24685/274191)

b)

```
#!/Bin/bash
virsh net-start default
```

c)

```
#!/Bin/bash
virsh net-destroy default
```

**2.** Edit the "sudoers" file to make the script: b) c) run with root privileges:

`$ sudo nano /etc/sudoers`

```
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/..your..path../net.sh
%sudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/..your..path../die.sh
```

**3.** Change the owner of the scripts b) c) to root:

```
$ sudo chown 700 /home/ham/..your..path../net.sh
$ sudo chown 700 /home/ham/..your..path../die.sh;
```

**4.** Create a rule in polkit for gnome-boxes. The answer: "how to do it?" is here: [simple_polkit_rule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203149/274191)

**5.** Edit files:

- org.gnome.Boxes.service

  `Exec=/home/..your..path../start.sh`
- org.gnome.Boxes.desktop

  `Exec=/home/..your..path../start.sh`

**6.** Now run the gnome-boxes application by clicking on its shortcut icon. Finished. From myself I added auto turn off connection when you close the gnome-boxes application.

Comment: Damn it :) Thank you very much for the solution. Everything with details described and Works! Nice idea. You saved my time.

Comment: No problem x) It's good to hear that.

Comment: I would recommend **not** allowing these `sudo`-able scripts to be writable by the user and **not** putting them in a directory owned by or writable by the user.   If your local user account is compromised, it provides an easy pathway to a root compromise if the scripts can be edited/replaced.  The scripts should be owned by root, with 755 perms, and in a directory owned by root (e.g. /usr/local/bin, also mode 755).

Comment: @cas Even if I give 700 permission? What is the importance of location when script can be edit by root <- only bc 700?

Comment: 700 would be OK too.  location is important because if the user has write access to the directory, they can replace the script.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply run any two or multiple commands with one prompt using `sh -c`
so in your case you can write

```
pkexec sh -c 'virsh net-start default && /home/user/program'
```

[Source](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-sudo-under-linux-or-unix/)

This method worked for me in command line and desktop files, let me know if it works in scripts

Comment: Is there a way to run the second command regardless of whether the first one was successful?

Comment: @mapto I think `sudo -- sh -c 'command1; command2'` might do it as in the source page it is implied that while using `&&` it will check first command and proceed to next if first was successful. However it could be an equivalent syntax. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Many have had similar issues with wanting to run GUI with su privileges. More recently I have looked into the lingering open terminal window. After searching this is what worked for me.

- my usage is invoking GUI with SU from the term and/or a shell script from ~/bin using aliases.

---

***GUI privilege escalation of "su" or "sudo" is not recommended and should     never be done with out knowledge of the risks of what your doing.***

---

- pkexec can be obtained by the following:

  ```
  sudo apt install policykit-1
  ```

---

- Edit the bottom of this file to where it looks likes this:

  ```
  sudo nano /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.policy
  ```
- yours should look like this:

  ```
  <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.lockdown">

    <description>Configure lock down for an action</description>

      <message>Authentication is required to configure lock down policy</message>

    <defaults>

      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>

      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>

      <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>

    </defaults>

    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/pklalockdown</annotate>

  </action>
  ```

  ---
- After that try:

  ```
  pkexec gedit
  ```

  ---

***Adding a custom bin path to terminal:***
- The Standard is to store users shell programs in

```
   /home/$USER/bin
```

or

```
   ~/bin
```

*These are the same location the first is the full path to file the second is short hand for

```
    /home/$USER/bin
```

- To add your user /bin to your $USER $PATH simply

  ```
  mkdir /home/$USER/bin
  ```
- terminal will now recognise your shell scripts or programs located in

  ```
  ~/bin
  ```

Example:

```
    $/path/to/file.sh
```

Becomes:

```
    $file.sh
```

ADD this to .bashrc

> export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
>
> Where "$HOME/bin" is the directory I assume you want to add. This
>   change is only temporary (it works only in the current session of the
>   shell) to make it permanent add the previous line to your .bashrc file
>   located in your home directory.

- I prefer this method of privilege escalation for gui apps because i can just pkexec in a shell script to run multiple programs and have the option to save credentials temporarily.
- you then can try and add an alias to ~/.bash_aliases:

  ```
  echo 'alias gedit="pkexec gedit"' >> ~/.bash_aliases
  ```

/PKEXEC /SU /GUI /GKsu /POLKIT /policykit-1