# Shortcutting in a loop

Tags: test, for

[Shortcutting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178199): `(expr1 && expr2)`, rather than an `if ... fi` statement. If `expr1`, `expr2`,... are to be generated by a loop, can you do it?

Here's a toy example:

```
$ for cond in {0,0,0}; do if [[ $cond = 0 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; break; fi; done && echo "true" || echo "false"
0
0
0
true

$ for cond in {0,1,0}; do if [[ $cond = 0 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; break; fi; done && echo "true" || echo "false"
0
1
true
```

How would I change the `if...fi` statement such that the first returns only `true`, and the second `false`? If I replace `echo 1` by `exit` within, well, the terminal window shuts off.

Comment: You don't have all of the elements of the `for` loop inside the `for` loop; can you elaborate what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: What elements of the `for` loop are missing?

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication; my interpretation is that you want to summarize the `for` loop by testing each value for `0`; since the `if` statement inside the `for` loop only sees one value at a time, it cannot shortcut.  Unless you want to exit the loop whenever you see a "false" value (such as `1` here)?

Comment: What it boils down to I think is how to I make the loop break and return status false when it encounters `$cond = 0`? Such that it can be chained with `&&` to the next command? I think I got it: `$ (for cond in {0,1,0}; do if [[ $cond = 0 ]]; then true; else false; exit; fi; done) && echo "true" || echo "false" 
false
` PS: from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059342/how-to-get-the-exit-status-a-loop-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

The exit status of the loop is that of the last command executed there, which is either `echo` or `break`, and both usually have a exit status of 0. So you need to preserve and check the status of the condition. I'd suggest using a function:

```bsh
loopcheck() {
for cond in {0,1,0}; do
  if [[ $cond = 0 ]]; then
    echo 0; 
  else
    ret=$?;   # preserve exit status of test
    echo 1; 
    return $ret;  # pass it on
  fi;
done
}

loopcheck && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

Another option is saving `$ret` like above and checking its value outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `for name in ...` loop relays the exit status of the last command executed.

When you `break` a loop, the `break` command itself has an exit status of 0 by default, which is therefore relayed by the `for`, thus making your `&&` test after the `done` be equal to `true`.

One way to work around that is as you said in your self-answer. That is a nice and clean one, and works well with any POSIX compliant shell.

But it has one drawback in that, by being a sub-shell, it doesn't fully share its [Execution Environment](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment)<sup>1</sup> with its "outer" shell. It does inherit it on beginning execution, but does not "propagate" it back to its "outer" parent on finishing execution, meaning for instance that any variable set or modified within the loop won't be seen after outside the loop.

Speaking for Bash, there is an alternative: you can avoid the sub-shell and still use `break` while forcing it to fail by passing it a `-1` argument, because `-1` is always an invalid number of loops to quit. Bash will display an error message for that, but you can mute it by redirecting to `2>/dev/null`.

However note also that this behavior is not properly POSIX compliant, because `break` is considered a [*special built-in*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), and a "special built-in" incurring into error [should exit a *non-interactive* shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01) (e.g. a script).

<sup><sup>1</sup>*[...]. Changes made to the **subshell** environment cannot affect the **shell’s** execution environment. [...]*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059342/how-to-get-the-exit-status-a-loop-in-bash) over the other answer (however useful) because it is closer to the requirement implicit in the question:

```
$ (for cond in {0,1,0}; do if [[ $cond = 0 ]]; then true; else false; exit; fi; done) && echo "true" || echo "false" false
```